# My app crashes when launched [Google Maps]

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I am trying to make simple google map application but its getting crash whenever I launch..

mainactivity.java

```
package com.example.google;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
GoogleMap map=null;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        if(map==null)
        {
        map=((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
        }
    }

}
```

activitymain.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.google.MainActivity" >

    <fragment 
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

manifext.example

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.google"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >
       <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <!-- Required to show current location -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />




    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="11"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />


                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

    <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="AIzaSyClHjmO6KkTTnr0r4vu7zvDNc-6KVDWwEA" />

</manifest>
```

logcat..

```
07-23 12:05:27.513: E/AndroidRuntime(23615): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-23 12:05:27.513: E/AndroidRuntime(23615): Process: com.example.google, PID: 23615
07-23 12:05:27.513: E/AndroidRuntime(23615): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.google/com.example.google.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #11: Error inflating class fragment
07-23 12:05:27.513: E/AndroidRuntime(23615):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2712)
07-23 12:05:27.513: E/AndroidRuntime(23615):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2777)
07-23 12:05:27.513: E/AndroidRuntime(23615):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:179)
07-23 12:05:27.513: E/AndroidRuntime(23615):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1462)
07-23 12:05:27.513: E/AndroidRuntime(23615):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
07-23 12:05:27.513: E/AndroidRuntime(23615):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
07-23 12:05:27.513: E/AndroidRuntime(23615):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5972)
07-23 12:05:27.513: E/AndroidRuntime(23615):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
07-23 12:05:27.513: E/AndroidRuntime(23615):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
07-23 12:05:27.513: E/AndroidRuntime(23615):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1399)
07-23 12:05:27.513: E/AndroidRuntime(23615):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1194)
07-23 12:05:27.513: E/AndroidRuntime(23615): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #11: Error inflating class fragment
07-23 12:05:27.513: E/AndroidRuntime(23615):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:770)
07-23 12:05:27.513: E/AndroidRuntime(23615):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:813)
07-23 12:05:27.513: E/AndroidRuntime(23615):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:511)
07-23 12:05:27.513: E/AndroidRuntime(23615):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:415)
07-23 12:05:27.513: E/AndroidRuntime(23615):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:366)
07-23 12:05:27.513: E/AndroidRuntime(23615):    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:249)
07-23 12:05:27.513: E/AndroidRuntime(23615):    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:106)
07-23 12:05:27.513: E/AndroidRuntime(23615):    at com.example.google.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:17)
07-23 12:05:27.513: E/AndroidRuntime(23615):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6289)
07-23 12:05:27.513: E/AndroidRuntime(23615):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1119)
07-23 12:05:27.513: E/AndroidRuntime(23615):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2665)
07-23 12:05:27.513: E/AndroidRuntime(23615):    ... 10 more
07-23 12:05:27.513: E/AndroidRuntime(23615): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: A required meta-data tag in your app's AndroidManifest.xml does not exist.  You must have the following declaration within the <application> element:     <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
07-23 12:05:27.513: E/AndroidRuntime(23615):    at com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.zzO(Unknown Source)
07-23 12:05:27.513: E/AndroidRuntime(23615):    at com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(Unknown Source)
07-23 12:05:27.513: E/AndroidRuntime(23615):    at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.zzy.zzai(Unknown Source)
07-23 12:05:27.513: E/AndroidRuntime(23615):    at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.zzy.zzah(Unknown Source)
07-23 12:05:27.513: E/AndroidRuntime(23615):    at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapsInitializer.initialize(Unknown Source)
07-23 12:05:27.513: E/AndroidRuntime(23615):    at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment$zzb.zztD(Unknown Source)
07-23 12:05:27.513: E/AndroidRuntime(23615):    at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment$zzb.zza(Unknown Source)
07-23 12:05:27.513: E/AndroidRuntime(23615):    at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.zza.zza(Unknown Source)
07-23 12:05:27.513: E/AndroidRuntime(23615):    at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.zza.onInflate(Unknown Source)
07-23 12:05:27.513: E/AndroidRuntime(23615):    at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment.onInflate(Unknown Source)
07-23 12:05:27.513: E/AndroidRuntime(23615):    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.onCreateView(FragmentManager.java:2130)
07-23 12:05:27.513: E/AndroidRuntime(23615):    at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:5610)
07-23 12:05:27.513: E/AndroidRuntime(23615):    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV11.callActivityOnCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImplV11.java:79)
07-23 12:05:27.513: E/AndroidRuntime(23615):    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.onCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:804)
07-23 12:05:27.513: E/AndroidRuntime(23615):    at android.support.v4.view.LayoutInflaterCompatHC$FactoryWrapperHC.onCreateView(LayoutInflaterCompatHC.java:44)
07-23 12:05:27.513: E/AndroidRuntime(23615):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:732)
07-23 12:05:27.513: E/AndroidRuntime(23615):    ... 20 more
```

Comment: From what i see, the error message even tells you that the `android:value` needs to be different

Comment: Read your logcat carefullyy....

Comment: You must have the following declaration within the <application> element:     <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"

Comment: Add this in your Manifest

      <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="XXXXXXX" />

Enter your Google value/key and then try

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which part of

> A required meta-data tag in your app's AndroidManifest.xml does not exist.  You must have the following declaration within the <application> element:     <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

you don't understand? You have only declared the API key, you should add the Play Services version as well.

Comment: i have added this but still there is error

Comment: Not the same error, I suppose?